# How to define XML payload structure for an Oracle Webservice?

Tags: java, xml, oracle, soap, weblogic

So far I've written a service that queries an existing database and gets information. It writes the information to a class, then adds it to a list of said classes.

```
@WebMethod 
@WebResult(name = "thing")
public List<Role> getThing {

    List<Thing> things = new ArrayList();

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        connection = Utils.getConnection();

        statement = connection.prepareStatement(PREPARED_STATEMENT);

        rs = statement.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){

            Thing thing = new Thing();

            thing.setONE(rs.getString("COLUMN_1"));
            thing.setTWO(rs.getString("COLUMN_2"));
            thing.setTHREE(rs.getString("COLUMN_3"));

            things.add(thing);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Utils.logException("ERROR");
    } finally {

        Utils.closeConnection(connection);
        Utils.closeResultSet(rs);
        Utils.closeStatement(statement);
    }
    return things;
}
```

The XML output needs to look like this:

```
<thing row=1>
    <ONE type="VARCHAR2" size=(size)>Thingy number One</ONE>
    <TWO type="VARCHAR2" size=(size)>Thingy number One</TWO>
    <THREE type="VARCHAR2" size=(size)>Thingy number One</THREE>
</thing>
<thing row=2>
    <ONE type="VARCHAR2" size=(size)>OTHER Thingy number One</ONE>
    <TWO type="VARCHAR2" size=(size)>OTHER Thingy number One</TWO>
    <THREE type="VARCHAR2" size=(size)>OTHER Thingy number One</THREE>
</thing>
```

How do I annotate the java web-service so that when the WSDL is consumed, it outputs that structure?

Thanks!

Comment: I find this question confusing because your sample code is so incomplete... `return roles` does nothing since it was never defined, you create `thing` in a loop but never add it to the array. And what does the xml output have to do with a WSDL, which also isn't shown? You'll need way more details to get a decent answer

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed the mistakes.

Comment: The thing is, I wrote the Java code to query the server and get the information I want. When I consume the webservice through SoapUI with the WSDL, I input some parameters(not shown) and I get back a small portion of the thing class.